# What's the price to access to the Gellert Baths sundeck?

Tags: tickets, price, budapest

I'm wondering if I have to pay for an adult ticket (5100-5700) in addition to the price for the sundeck daily ticket (1800 HUF) to access only to the sundeck at Gellert Baths in Budapest. [The price scheme](http://www.gellertbath.com/prices-location.php) is a bit confusing to me. We are not interested in the baths (we prefer Széchenyi), but we are interested to access to the sundeck.

Comment: Same as @pnuts. In a distant age, I remember visiting the sun deck, which I presume is the area around the outside pool. I'm quite sure that was charged on top of the regular entry fee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [February 18, 2016 blog by Canadian Wanderer Ian Glen](http://canadianwanderer.com/taking-the-plunge-in-budapest/), the sundeck is an separate, additional fee:

> At both Széchenyi and Gellért men and women bath together and swimsuits – normally tiny Speedos for the men as this is Europe after all – are worn in all but a few clothing optional locations. Expect prices for an afternoon of relaxation in the baths to be around CAD$20 with locker rental but extras such as massage, admission to the outdoor naturist (read nudist)  summer sundeck, or something called a chocolate treatment will all add to the overall price.